# НН в имени Иоанн

Tags: этимология, ономастика, удвоенные-буквы

Почему имя Иоанн пишется с двумя Н?

Answer (score 2):

В русский язык имя пришло из греческого, где звучало как *Ιωάννης* (Иоаннос). Как видите, в греческом варианте имени удвоенное НН, которое передалось "по наследству" в наш язык. В греческий язык имя пришло из первоисточника - древнееврейского языка (יחנן‎ Йоханан, Йеѓоханан). Судя по транскрипции, две согласных Н и здесь в наличии.

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что так правильно.
А какого ответа вы хотели?

Comment: Наверно, исторического объяснения.
Иван-то пишется с одной Н.

Answer (score 0):

Имя Иоанн не греческого, а древнееврейского происхождения, как и имя Анна (Иоанна). В древнееврейском оно употреблялось с НН. Русский вариант с Н - результат лингвистического опрощения.

Comment: В русский язык названное древнееврейское имя пришло все-таки через греческий (см. Этимологический словарь Фасмера)

Comment: Анна ведь, кажется, сначала было мужским именем? "Первосвященники Анна и Каиафа".

Comment: С Анной - некоторые непонятки. Есть имя Ханна (миловидная) - оно чисто женское, но в Библии и Еваглелиях не упоминается. И есть имя Хаанаан (милостивый) - вот его его-то носил тесть Каиафы. Честно слово, не знаю, одно ли это имя. Возможно, на греческой почве произошло смешение.
  
И судя по всему, "Анна" к "Иоанне" прямого отношения не имеет. Иоанна, если не ошибаюсь, - позднейшее прененсение мужского имени, Иоанн (иоханаан), что означает "данный богом".

Comment: Да, меня как раз смутила эта "Иоанна".